# How to understand isEqualNode() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand isEqualNode() method in JavaScript which apparently according to definition provided by W3 schools is like this

**The isEqualNode() method checks if two nodes are equal.**

> Two nodes are equal if all the following conditions are true:
>
> They have the same Node Type
>
> They have the same nodeName, NodeValue, localName, nameSpaceURI and
>   prefix
>
> They have the same childNodes with all the descendants
>
> They have the same attributes and attribute values (the attributes
>   does not have be in the same order)

Now here is some variant of code that i have tried to satisfy the following conditions as per the definition

```js
function main(x,y)
{
  
/* 
To check whether node are equal are not using isEqualNode()
*/

var item1 = document.getElementById(x).firstElementChild;
var item2 = document.getElementById(y).firstElementChild; 
var result = item1.isEqualNode(item2); 
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="box1"><p>I am abc</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box2"><p>I am abc</p>
  </div>
  <div id="box3"><p> I am Xyz
   </p>
  </div>
  <div id="box4">
    <p>
      I am Xyz
      </p>
  </div>
  <div id="box5">
    <p>
      
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="box6">
    <p>
      
    </p>
   </div>
  <p id="output">
    
  </p>
  <button onclick="main('box1','box2')">Compare Box1 and Box2</button>
  <button onclick="main('box1','box3')">Compare Box1 and Box 3</button>
  <button onclick="main('box2','box3')">Compare Box2 and Box3</button>
  <button onclick="main('box3','box4')">Compare Box3 and Box4</button>
  <button onclick="main('box5','box6')">Compare Box5 and Box6</button>
  <button onclick="main('box1','box6')">Compare Box1 and Box6</button>
</body>
```

Now if you observe the O/P for the following different condition here is the list of O/P you will get:

> Compare Box1 and Box2 = true
>
> Compare Box1 and Box3= false
>
> Compare Box2 and Box3 = false
>
> Compare Box3 and Box4 = false
>
> Compare Box5 and Box6 = true
>
> Compare Box1 and Box6 = false

Now, as per definition it satisfy the following conditions

> They have the same Node Type
>
> They have the same childNodes with all the descendants

Then why it return false when it's **text value** is changed which is the case while comparing
***"Box1 and Box3***" or even when its an empty node with no **text value** which is the case while comparing ***"Box1 and Box6"***.

It also return false for comparing ***"Box3 and Box4"*** which has the same node  as well its **text value** only its written in different fashion.

But irrespective of that it should return true because all of them as **p** as its descendant child.

Comment: I'm not totally sure why you think those nodes should be equal. Having a different text value means they have different descendants (because text values are nodes).

Comment: Do NOT use w3schools as a reference. It is NOT an official site. The information is often misleading and wrong. I prefer MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isEqualNode

Comment: @some I wouldn't say that the information is often misleading or wrong, it just isn't as thorough as other sites. There's been a lot of progress since http://www.w3fools.com/ first started.

Comment: @4castle Sure, it is better now than when w3fools started, but it still has issues. I have used it, and been bitten numerous times. My recommendation is still to AVOID w3schools. If you use it, be very careful and always verify the information with a more reputable source.

Comment: @some Thanks for letting me know about this i wasn't aware of this till know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the DOM, everything is a Node. Elements are nodes (of course), but so are attributes (historically), comments, documents, document fragments, doctypes and, yes, text.

All text is contained in a text node.

Let's prove this. If we loop through the `childNodes` of, say, `#box4` in your code above:

```js
for (let child of document.querySelector('#box4').childNodes) {
  console.log(child.nodeType);
}
```

```html
<div id="box4">
  <p>
    I am Xyz
  </p>
</div>
```

This logs `3` then `1` then `3` again. If we look this up on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType), we learn that `3` is the `nodeType` of a `Text` node, while `1` is the `nodeType` of an `Element` node.

If we were to loop through `#box3`, we'd get a different result:

```js
for (let child of document.querySelector('#box3').childNodes) {
  console.log(child.nodeType);
}
```

```html
<div id="box3"><p> I am Xyz
  </p>
</div>
```

This logs `1` then `3` (because you've got a `p` element node followed by a text node containing only white space).

The short answer, then, is that "the same childNodes" includes text content.

Comment: so as per this isEqualNode() perform a deep comparison to compare both element as well as the text node inside them correct ?

Comment: @MehulChachada [Essentially, yes](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-equals). Every child node must pass the same `isEqualNode` test, and every type of node counts.

Comment: "_we learn that 3 is the nodeType of a Text node_" which is a warning when you're using `DOMParser` with XML that has "[insignificant whitespace](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/wang-whitespace.html#:%7E:text=Significant%20whitespace%20is,of%20the%20document.)", as the `DOMParser` will [go all XHTML on it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76474236/1028230) and say they're different nodes if anything about that text node changes (afaict), though semantically they're the same. Great example code btw.

Answer (score 2):

The [specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-equals) says

> A node A equals a node B if all of the following conditions are true:
>   A and B’s nodeType attribute value is identical.
>   …
>   **Each child of A equals the child of B at the identical index.**

So, it's a deep comparison, every child needs to be same, including text nodes.